# Insertar la hora desde una DateTimePiker

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo un Datetimpiker pero de este solo quiero capturar la hora, en el format le puse la propiedad time y me quedo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**campos de bd**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

así lo necesitaba, esos dos campos están en la base de datos como tipo time, pero desde la aplicación los sigue guardando como datetime no basta solo con cambiar la propiedad format a time ¿?

como puedo guardar la hora desde la aplicación y cuando esta ya este en la base de datos capture la hora y me la muestre tal y como esta en la bd

```
 private void BtnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (operacion == "Insertar")
            {

                objetask.FInicio1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateHInicio.Value);
                objetask.HFin1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFin.Value);       
                objetask.Notas1 = txtNotas.Text;
                objetask.InsertarActividad();
                MessageBox.Show("Insertado correctamente");
                this.Close();
            }
            else if (operacion == "Editar")
            {

                objetask.HInicio1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateHInicio.Value);
                objetask.HFin1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateHFin.Value);
                objetask.Notas1 = txtNotas.Text;
                objetask.ActualizarActividad();
                MessageBox.Show("Se edito correctamente");
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

**excepción**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 public void InsertarActividad()
        {
            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "InsertarActividad";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocRefe", DocRefe);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NomActivi", NomActivi);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodTarea", CodTarea);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codtipo", CodTipo);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codprio", CodPrio);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codresp", CodResp);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codestad", CodEstad);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fcreacion", FCreacion);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@finicio", FInicio);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ffin", FFin);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HInicio", HInicio);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HFin", HFin);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodComplet", CodComplet);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notas", Notas);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    command.Parameters.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
```

no se por que me dice que el error viene de bd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas tomando una fecha del `DateTimePicker` que no es valida porque nunca permites su seleccion, solo estas definiendo la hora, por eso la fecha que pasas por parametro es invalida y el parametro la rechaza.

Si analizamos los tipos de parametros

[Date and Time Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/date-and-time-data)

observaras que debes asignar un `TimeSpan` y no un `DateTime`

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();  
parameter.ParameterName = "@HInicio";  
parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Time;  
parameter.Value =  HInicio1.TimeOfDay;
```

Usando el `TimeOfDay` obtendras el tipo de datos para el `time` que debes enviar en el parametro

Podrias probar si funciona mas simple con el

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HInicio", HInicio.TimeOfDay);
```

Comment: Amigo me puedes ayudar con algo es que vi una publicacion tuya sobre esto y es lo mismo que me pasa a mi  esto me funciono pero ahora me sale otra cosa   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/1ba559d7-0e17-4b7e-9d0a-9004358b8fa9/error-en-consulta-no-se-puede-convertir-implicitamente-el-tipo-string-en-en-systemdatetime?forum=vcses

Comment: que otra cosa ? quizas si es un tema diferente podrias abrir una nueva pregunta